# add a function to an exported type without breaking the existing contract

Tags: typescript

I want to add a new function to an exported type, the type is already being used in prod so dont want to rename anything or introduce breaking changes.

```
import * as BunyanLogger from 'bunyan';
import init from './logger';

export type Logger = BunyanLogger;
```

I tried to use an interface instead of the type but it will require me to implement all methods on the `BunyanLogger`.

I would like to extend the `Logger` type with an additional method, I have tried intersection shown below, but didnt work either:

```
export type Logger = BunyanLogger & {
  debugInPlace: (featureRole?:string, ...params: any[]) => void;
};
```

is there a way to add an additional method to the `Logger` type withouth having to re implement or delegate to the methods in the `BunyanLogger` type?

Comment: Types cannot be augmentated. You can use an interface and add make the method as optional. `export {}; declare module 'bunyan' { interface BunyanLogger { debugInPlace?: (featureRole?:string, ...params: any[]) => void }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by importing the whole `bunyan` namespace and implementing it as an interface.

```js
import Logger from 'bunyan';
import * as bunyanLogger from "bunyan";

export class ExtendedLogger extends Logger implements bunyanLogger {
  constructor(options: Logger.LoggerOptions) {
    super(options);
  }
}
```